# MySQL connecting issue with Zend App

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, connection, zend

I've set up a `VirtualHost` on my local machine (Windows XP with XAMP installed) and installed `Zend` there as well, now I'm trying to connect to the `MySQL` database and I get the following error message:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on ''myhost.com'' (10060)
```

All the tips I've found via `Google` haven't helped. I use `Kaspersky AntiVirus` and have added port `3306` to the allowed list for `MySQL` and Apache. I've also pinged `myhost.com:3306` and get a response (with IP address `67.63.50.51`), though `localhost:3306` and `127.0.0.1:3306` aren't found. I've checked that other WebApps can still access `MySQL` if the virtual host is pointed at them instead and my non Zend Apps do work.

I guess I have to do something further to the port, or maybe force the App to use a different port, but am not sure how to do either.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> localhost:3306 and 127.0.0.1:3306 aren't found

`ping` cannot be used to verify a port's state, as it's in a different TCP/IP layer and doesn't use a port. Try

> telnet localhost 3306

If you can connect, you should see a number of unintelligible characters. This is the MySQL connection ready string.

It seems other apps can access MySQL - when Zend is configured, try running `xampp-portcheck.exe` (in your xampp root) and, if all's ok, starting `xampp-control.exe` to ensure the MySQL service is running (although it seems likely it is).

> I've also pinged myhost.com:3306 and get a response (with ip address 67.63.50.51),

Is 67.63.50.51 your internet facing IP address? It you are setting this up for local dev you're better off configuring the vhost's hostname in your `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and directing it to 127.0.0.1 - if 67.63.50.51 isn't your address, you're testing another server (it currently redirects to a Dutch holding page).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming at least one of the App is *ALREADY* able to connect to `MySQL` server, you do not need to open more ports with `Kaspetsky AntiVirus`, so if I were you I'd look the app that *IS* able to connect and copy database `hostname` from there and into your new app.